# Custom view isn't drawing text where I touch it

Tags: android

I'm writing a custom view that should draw text wherever the user touches it:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class TouchTextView extends View
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path path = new Path();
    final String text = "Touched";

    public TouchTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for XML Inflation
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public TouchTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public TouchTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    public TouchTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        mPaint.setTextSize(50);
        mPaint.setSubpixelText(true);//Enabling this flag causes glyph advances to be computed with subpixel accuracy.
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPaint.getTextPath(text, 0, text.length(), eventX, eventY, path);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // nothing to do
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // nothing to do
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

my XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.test_app.MainActivity">

    <android.test_app.TouchTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**PROBLEM:** no text is drawn when I touch the view. Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Try calling path.close(); to properly close the path after getTextPath.

Comment: OnTouchListener quick tip : always add `ACTION_CANCEL` to avoid unwanted glitches and malfunctions

Comment: ACTION_CANCEL only matters if you're trying to do something on release or on movement.  If you only care about down, like here, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call `invalidate();` is never called because you are leaving the function by `return` statement.

So change your code to the following:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPaint.getTextPath(text, 0, text.length(), eventX, eventY, path);
                path.close();
                invalidate();
                return true;
```

Comment: He can also remove it from the end of the function, as with this code he only needs to call it on down and all other invalidates are wasted.  Unless he wants it to follow his finger, in which case he needs to code the ACTION_MOVE as well.

Comment: It was a combination: invalidate() needed to be called before the return, but also path.close() needed to be called